# Is $\sum \frac{1}{n}\sin^{2}\frac{1}{n}$ divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The question asks which one of the following is divergent?

(a)$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sin^{2}\frac{1}{n}$

(b)$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log n$

(c)$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sin \frac{1}{n}$

(d)$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\tan \frac{1}{n}$

I was thinking to use the camparison test, that since, $\sin^{2}\frac{1}{n}\le 1$, it implies $\frac{\sin^{2}\frac{1}{n}}{n}\le \frac{1}{n}$.Then since $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent, $\sum \frac{1}{n}\sin^{2}\frac{1}{n}$ is also divergent.
But the correct answer is only (b).So am I wrong somewhere with my arguments, please explain.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something **less** than a divergent sequence may very well converge- so, your argument doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

$a_n \leq \frac 1 n$ does not make $\sum a_n$ divergent. Example:  $a_n=0$ for all $n$.

$\sin^{2}(\frac 1 n) \leq (\frac  1n)^{2}$ and $ \sum \frac 1 {n^{3}}$ is convergent. So $\sum \frac 1 n \sin^{2} (\frac 1 n)$ is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

(a)
$$\sum\frac 1n\sin^2\frac 1 n \leq \sum\frac  1{n^3}<\infty$$

(b)
$$\sum \frac 1n\log n>\sum\frac 1n=\infty$$

(c)
$$\sum \frac 1{n^2}\sin\frac 1n\leq \sum\frac  1{n^3}<\infty$$

(d)
$$\sum \frac 1n\tan \frac 1n\leq \sum\frac 1{n^2}<\infty$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1733325)

Comment: @ParasKhosla does this look like an answer now?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to see what are the convergent series it is noticing that, for $x$ near of zero you have that $\sin x\approx x$. More formally you have that

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1
$$

The previous result can be used to see that you can exchange $\sin (1/n)$ by $1/n$ in your series to see if they will be convergent. Then you can see easily that every of your series with a sine can be compared with the series $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\frac1{n^2}$ what surely you knows that it is convergent. Therefore the unique possibility for a divergent series is (b).